# Setting same Height and width of ImageView in percentage that is in Listview

Tags: android, layout, android-listview, height, width

I have a listview which look like this:

[image]

but it is after giving hardcoded hight and width in xml.
This is my XML for listview adaptor:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"    
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:weightSum="7"
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 > 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:textSize="18sp" 

   />


<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center"
    android:src="@drawable/bluearrowmap"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am giving First image 2% width but the problem is that now how can i give height to that imageview same like it will take width from difference devices.Because i want this image to be a square just like it is in picture.
i have tried this piece of code in my adaptor class

```
        ViewTreeObserver vto = holder.image.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    holder.image.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    int finalHeight = holder.image.getMeasuredHeight();
                    int finalWidth = holder.image.getMeasuredWidth();

                    holder.image.getLayoutParams().height=finalWidth;

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

i am writting this code in my getview of adaptor class.it works fine sometime but sometime it needs a scroll down to set the height of imagview according to width.
Can someone plz help? i have tried every solution on internet but all in vain.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to properly use weight in LinearLayout then no need to change any height or width value at runtime :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for such quick reply
Actually i am downloading images from internet and they have large resolution. so your layout does not working good.
do you have another way?

Comment: Then you have to use same static height or width for ImageView.

Comment: Yes i did it. Thanks @Haresh

Comment: Good luck dear and again glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Extends image view and set it like below:

```
public class SquareImageView  extends ImageView {

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
  }

}
```

Comment: where to use this class? can you give any demo code?
thanks for reply though

Comment: <your.package.name.SquareImageView

/> use this where you are using ImgaeView

Comment: it is throwing Error inflating class com.mypackagename.SquareImageView
though i think your answer is my solution.but what about this error?

Comment: Have you added proper constructor for SquareViewClass as its required for ImageView.. search on google you will get many examples of that, the class i have provided is showing only half part (i.e. wothout constructor)